# equations of sides of triangles; find largest angle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If the sides of a triangle are $2x+3$, $x^2 + 3x + 3$, and $x^2 + 2x$, find the greatest interior angle of a triangle.

The answer is $120$ degrees.

I was hoping to find a formula to relate all the three sides, then use cosine law to find an angle. If I use the sine law, I don't have an angle.... If I use the cosine law, I also don't have an angle (and you also have to square terms; takes more time?). Pythagorean doesn't assume a right triangle.

Do I assume a value for $x$? How so? I am totally lost. Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the three sides given the largest one is obviously $x^2+3x+3$.So we apply cosine rule for the angle opposite to this side.

If we consider the angle $\theta$ then we get

$$cos\theta= \frac {(x^2+2x)^2+(2x+3)^2-(x^2+3x+3)^2} {2(x^2+2x)(2x+3)}$$.

Simlpify it and then you will get $$cos\theta=-\frac{1} {2}$$ which will give you the angle as 120.

Answer (score 4):

Use cosine rule. It's really quite trivial when you keep the algebra simple.

The longest side is $x^2 + 3x + 3$, so the greatest angle lies opposite this. To show that that's the longest side, you simply need to sketch the curves for $x>0$, which is the region that matters, since for $x \leq 0$, the side of length $x^2 + 2x$ becomes zero or negative, which is impossible.

Apply the cosine rule:

$(x^2 + 3x + 3)^2 = (2x+3)^2 + (x^2 + 2x)^2 - 2(2x+3)(x^2+2x)\cos\theta$

When simplifying, avoid opening up the brackets immediately. Use identities like $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ to keep your life simple.

Working in this careful fashion, we get:

$(x+3)(2x^2 + 5x + 3) - (2x+3)^2= -2(2x+3)(x^2 + 2x)\cos \theta$

$(x+3)(2x +3)(x+1) - (2x+3)^2= -2(2x+3)(x^2 + 2x)\cos \theta$

It is permitted to cancel $2x+3$ from both sides as this cannot be zero (since $x>0$).

So:

$(x+3)(x+1) - 2x - 3 = -2(x^2 + 2x)\cos\theta$

$x^2 + 4x + 3 - 2x - 3 = -2(x^2 + 2x)\cos\theta$

$(x^2 + 2x) = -2(x^2 + 2x)\cos\theta$

giving $\cos \theta = -\frac 12$ and $\theta = 120^{\circ}$

Answer (score 1):

since it can't possibly depend on x, put x = 1 and solve the 3,5,7 for the angle opposite the side 7 using the law of cosines

Comment: Actually, you only know that the answer isn't $x$-dependent because the stated solution is 120 degrees. However, if asked the question without any choices or stated solution, the only way is to go through the algebra and prove that the answer is $x$-independent. Of course, if this question was a multi-choice with various angles stated, my first instinct would be to plug $x=1$ and get a quick answer (which is actually what I did here as well).